# Render innerHTML inside .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss

Trying to Sanitize a text HTML and render it inside another html , this is what I tried,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").html(sanitizeHTML("Hello <b>world!</b>"));
  });
});

function sanitizeHTML(str){
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.textContent = str;
    return temp.innerHTML;
}
```

Getting output as

> `Hello <b>world!</b>`

Need proper HTML as

> `Hello world!`

Here is a working sample to try out,
https://jsfiddle.net/mb9ksq3z/

Please note this is not another remove HTML from text question , the whole point is to sanitise the HTML for open vulnerabilities for 'Fortify Code Scans' and directly putting string inside .html() is direct vulnerability.

Comment: Just use `text()`. https://jsfiddle.net/h57Lynca/1/

Comment: tried text() , makes it 'Hello &lt;b&gt;world!&lt;/b&gt;'

Comment: Well what do you want it to be? The text has HTML markup in it.

Comment: `makes it 'Hello &lt;b&gt;world!&lt;/b&gt;' `... so you're hard coding the input string...? If so just remove the HTML from it manually...? Am I missing something here?

Comment: please try the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mb9ksq3z/

Comment: If you return `temp.innerText` from the function that might get you what you want, but it's not entirely clear what that is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will the text be 'bold' if i remove html manually

Comment: No - because you removed the HTML. But the same is true if you remove it programmatically, as shown in the Fiddle in my first comment

Comment: cannot do that , its a open vulnerability in Fortify scans , whole point is to sanitise the HTML

Comment: That makes no sense as the logic in my fiddle solution is identical. If you're worried about security that much, then you shouldn't be working with user-generated HTML in the first instance.

Comment: Try this function: `function sanitizeHTML(str) { return $('<div/>').html(str).text(); }` I tested this code and it works for me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it comes from a database , cant help it , do we  have a work around ? and why this was marked duplicate ? I dont see anything similar in the tagged duplicate question !!

Comment: @sajanvz See my comment: I provided an answer in a comment. It uses the jQuery text() function to remove HTML tags from a text string. I hope this helps.

Comment: @ktm5124 that seems to work , but may not close the vulnerability , let me run the scan again

Comment: @sajanvz If your website uses jQuery (which it does) then I think the jQuery text() function is one of the best ways of doing this. `function sanitizeHTML(str) {return $('<div/>').html(str).text();}` It's a one-line function. By the way, you asked a very good question. Thank you for asking an interesting question about removing HTML tags from a string of text. It's the kind of task that is well suited to a library function, because without a library function it would take a lot of work.

Comment: `it comes from a database` in that case, sanitizing it on the front end is the worst solution possible - especially if code quality/security is your concern. Do this properly and sanitise the content of your database before you send it to the front end. Anything else is a hacky workaround.

Comment: @ktm5124 as expected , this opens vulnerability at this line , var temp = $('<div/>').html(str);

Comment: @sajanvz I see... if you give the user control over what gets passed to sanitizeHTML, it's possible there is a vulnerability. Because that allows for something called "code injection" or "script injection". You might have to write a function that generates safe content from a user input. One example of safe content would be: a character set consisting of a-zA-Z1-9. `function safeContent(str)` outputs a string consisting of the characters a-zA-Z1-9, that is, a very limited subset of ASCII.

Comment: @sajanvz So you can create a legal character set (a-zA-Z1-9) which is a very limited subset of ASCII. (You can add punctuation characters like .,;!). Then you can write a function `safeContent(str)` that removes every illegal character and everything inside HTML tags `<...>`. The function `safeContent(str)` will generate a safe string that only consists of characters from the legal character set. (We defined the legal character set to be a-zA-Z1-9). The function `safeContent` can also impose a length limit: the output string can be N characters or less where N is the length limit.

Answer (score 0):

change your function to:

```js
function sanitizeHTML(str)
{
   let tmp = document.createElement("div");
   tmp.innerHTML = str;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Comment: No , doesn't help

Comment: Sorry wrong var, fixed it. try again.